# problem carrying over a get value to form

Tags: php, forms

I am having some trouble with an online tutorial I'm following. It should be a simple variable assignment. I shouldn't need to show code its more of a logic problem I will try to explain as best I can.

I have a page that displays a list of blog posts in a table. the columns are as follows

```
post id --- author --- title --- category --- status --- image --- tags --- comments --- date ---
```

there are edit and delete buttons to the right of each row. the problem is regarding the edit feature.
when I click edit it sends a $_GET variable "post_id" to another page. this page is just a form with fields for all the relevant info for the selected blog post. the data is loaded into each form field so when the page loads all the relevant "to be updated" data is there. to update the user simply deletes the current field content, enters the new value and hits edit.

here's where things go astray. all data is loaded into each form input field excluding the post id. when the user hits enter on the form the data is sent to a function that updates the data on the condition "WHERE post_id = the $_GET["post_id"]". this is the value sent from the original posts table page when the user hits edit. how do I bring that id along to the update script (sent to a different page) when the user clicks enter on the update form?

I tried the following just to see if it was being received.

```
form data recieved then

if(isset($_POST["edit_post"])){     //the name of the update button
    $post_id = $_GET["p_id"];
    echo $post_id;
}
```

I know I could just use another input field for the id but the tutorial doesn't do that. I tried to replicate directly from the tutorial with the above test but it doesn't echo out anything, thanks for taking the time to read all this. I appreciate your reply.

Comment: `isset` check is wrong. something like this `isset($_POST['edit_post']))`

Comment: @Gowri that is correct but i had it in the original code i left it out of my post by mistake. i have edited the original post to correct that. im actually getting the following error ```Notice: Undefined index: p_id in  ```

Comment: Well, you can concatenate the value of `$_GET["p_id"]` to the `action` attribute of the form, something like `action="update.php?p_id=1"`

Comment: @Carl Binalla nice thankyou

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use another input for the `$_GET["p_id"]`, you can instead concatenate it to the `action` attribute of the form, something like this:

```
<?php
$p_id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['p_id'], ENT_QUOTES);
?>
<form action="update.php?p_id=<?php echo $p_id ; ?>" method="POST">
// inputs
</form>
```